# Cell not updated - VB.net, oledb

Tags: vb.net, oledb

Ive been wrestling with the code below for a long time now, and just when i thought it works it doesnt, and it doesnt even give me an error.

```
            Dim sql As String = "UPDATE " & table & " SET ArithmeticScore = @score WHERE DateAscending = " & todaysdate
            Using connection As New OleDbConnection(conn)
                Using command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
                    connection.Open()
                    command.Parameters.Add("@score", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = score
                    MsgBox("score was added = " & score)
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    connection.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
```

`todaysdate` currently holds the value `27/04/2020` as `date`

`conn` holds the connection string, `table` holds the table name.

The messagebox outputs what it is meant to, with `score` having a decimal value that should be added into the table.

The purpose of this code is to update the `ArithmeticScore` column in the table, Where `DateAscending = 27/04/2020`. When the program is finished, and i check the database, the cell remains blank. Why could this be?

Comment: This is **STILL** subject to sql injection issues. Use a parameter for the Date comparison, too.

Comment: Also, `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns a number.  If it's greater than zero, the query worked.

Comment: Do you have more than one table with fields called ArithmeticScore and DateAscending?

Comment: Yes I do, @Mary

Comment: Are you saying you have one table for every student? I am do DBA but I think that might be a poor design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because executed query can not find required record.
Try to set correct type for sql parameter for `DateAscending` column.

```vb
Dim sql As String = 
    $"UPDATE {table} SET ArithmeticScore = @score WHERE DateAscending = @todaysdate"

Using connection As New OleDbConnection(conn)
    Using command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
        command.Parameters.Add("@score", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = score
        command.Parameters.Add("@todaysdate", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now.Date

        connection.Open()
        Dim affectedRows As Integer = command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        ' Check or display that affectedRows is greater than zero
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Yes, in the example I used `DateTime.Now.Date` for that, but you can replace it with any value.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked for me. However the value `score` in the program is a `decimal`, its value is 9.9655, and in the database it is now a value of 10. the data type of `ArithmeticScore` is `Number`. Do I need to store a decimal as something else? `Short Text` Maybe?

Comment: Never Mind... turns out there's a drop down menu. I've got it thanks